# Binding Dropdown selected value to Label in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to VS 2010 and MVC2.Here i had populated a dropdownlist from database. My HomeControler Source Code will be 
`
namespace SampleControls.Controllers
{

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    SControlsDataContext data = new SControlsDataContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
     {
         var Emp = from prod in data.Emps
                   select prod;
         ViewData["Emps"] = Emp;
         return View();
     }      

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

}
`

and my Index.aspx will be

`<% using (Html.BeginForm())
       { %>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("lstProducts", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Emps"], "Id", "Name"), new { onChange = "onSelectedIndexChanged()" })%>
    <% } %>`

what i want is " on the SelectedIndexChanged, the selected value should be displayed in a label.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function onSelectedIndexChanged() 
      {
       //i know i should write the code here for binding the dropdown selected value to label... But, i dont know how to do this.
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %> 
    <%= Html.DropDownList("lstProducts", 
        new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Emps"], "Id", "Name"), 
        new { onchange = "onSelectedIndexChanged(this.value)" })%> 
<% } %>

<div id="foo"></div>
```

and then:

```
function onSelectedIndexChanged(value) {
    document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = value;
}
```

---

UPDATE:

In order to get the selected text:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %> 
    <%= Html.DropDownList("lstProducts", 
        new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Emps"], "Id", "Name"), 
        new { onchange = "onSelectedIndexChanged(this)" })%> 
<% } %>

function onSelectedIndexChanged(select) {
    var text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = text;
}
```

---

UPDATE 2:

The same could be achieved with jquery:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %> 
    <%= Html.DropDownList("lstProducts", 
        new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Emps"], "Id", "Name"), 
        new { id="myselect" })%> 
<% } %>
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myselect').change(function() {
        var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $('#foo').html(text);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. I want to get the selected Text, but now selected value is coming..

Comment: I am very new to MVC 2. Whether you are having any sample application which includes Dropdown list(Selected change event) ,Checkbox (checked Change Event),Radio Button (checked Change Event) etc..

Comment: @Sridhar R, this is more javascript problem than ASP.NET MVC. Have you looked at [jquery](http://jquery.com/)? It could greatly simplify your javascript development and the site contains many useful examples.

Comment: Ya,i am started working in JQuery also. If there is a Basic sample appication means, its will be easy for me to go through the structure.

Comment: Hi, in your JQuery in this line " $('#foo').html(text);" you are binding the value to DIV. If i want to bind it in the Textbox means what should i do.Whether this is correct " $('#MyName').Text(text);"

Comment: Thanks once again..I itself find that "$('#MyName').val(text);"